# Disabling Swagger Bundle in DropWizard

Tags: java, rest, swagger, dropwizard

I am looking to disable the swagger functionality / endpoint in a production environment based on a config value.

How would I go about this?

I believe the best way to achieve this is not to add the bundle during the execution of the initialize method when a DropWizard application first starts.

The issue with this solution is that you cannot access the configuration get methods that are populated from the values in the YAML/YML file. These values are available are available when we the application gets to the run method.

Here is my initialise method from the application class

```
@Override
public void initialize(Bootstrap<Configuration> bootstrap) {
    LOGGER.debug("initialize");
    bootstrap.setConfigurationSourceProvider(new SubstitutingSourceProvider(bootstrap.getConfigurationSourceProvider(),
            new EnvironmentVariableSubstitutor(false)));

    bootstrap.addBundle(new SwaggerBundle<Configuration>() {
        @Override
        protected SwaggerBundleConfiguration getSwaggerBundleConfiguration(Configuration configuration) {
            return configuration.swaggerBundleConfiguration;
        }
    });
}
```

If I need to clarify more please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an older version of DropWizard at the time.

After updating, there were new methods available including **setIsEnabled()**

This is what was added to solve the issue.

```
bootstrap.addBundle(new SwaggerBundle<Configuration>() {
        @Override
        protected SwaggerBundleConfiguration getSwaggerBundleConfiguration(Configuration configuration) {
            if(!configuration.getSwaggerEnabled()){
                configuration.swaggerBundleConfiguration.setIsEnabled(false);
            }
            return configuration.swaggerBundleConfiguration;
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You can set an environment variable in production and use it to decide whether to include SwaggerBundle or not. For example:

```
if (!"prod".equalsIgnoreCase(System.getenv("ENVIRONMENT"))) {
  bootstrap.addBundle(new SwaggerBundle<Configuration>() { ... }
}
```